# Meaning of the expression, "gracefully touched" here

Tags: meaning, expressions

> When I was ten I was suddenly confronted with the anguish of moving from the old [only?] home I had ever known. My whole life, brief as it was, had been spent in that big old house, gracefully touched with the laughter and tears of four generations.

What does "gracefully touched" mean here? What does "gracefully touched with the laughter and tears of four generations" modify?

Comment: Please give the source of quotations! I'm assuming that the original read _the only home I had ever known_. It's poetic language, implying that four generations of the author's family had lived in the house and it was full of both happy and unhappy memories of their life there.

Comment: sorry, the sentence is from the article in my textbook

Comment: Those two words don't really add much. It's just a slightly poetic, nicer way of saying "In that house, __there was__ a lot of laughter and tears". By 'touched' is implied 'experienced' or 'had a lot of'. As to 'gracefully',  it means 'with grace', but intending 'lightly' or ... frankly it's kind of meaningless, the author is just trying to make it sound fancy, a different way of saying that they have good and bad memories but still remembering them fondly.

Comment: There's an anthropomorphism. It's as if the house has absorbed the more pleasant memories associated with the inhabitants, so 'feels' congenial. The ambiguity you point out (is the referent described by 'gracefully touched ...' the house or the writer?) doesn't really matter here.

Comment: When reading "laughter and tears of four generations", I imagine a house where the writer had Siblings, Parents, Grand-Parents & at least one Great-Grand-Parent .... It looks like, "gracefully touched" refers to "My whole life", which was "gracefully influenced" by these 4 generations. Alternately, the writer may have meant it to refer to "that big old house", but then it would have been better to write "that big old house, **which had been** gracefully touched with the laughter" ....

Comment: Think of ‘graced’ in the same sense as growing old gracefully.